# Custom spray json format of Either[TimeSlot,DateSlot] stuck in some kind of type-inference loop

Tags: scala, serialization, spray-json, either

> My spray json serialization does not seem to work, as my tests just keeps running, when i am trying to serialize an Either[TimeSlot, DateSlot] object to **JsValue**, and vice-versa when i am trying to parse a json string and convert it to **Either[TimeSlot,DateSlot]** object.

I have been reading some others with same issues, just with a Seq[Either[int,String], but the solution was hardly understood. Furthermore i have tried using the standardized Either json format, but problem is, that i need to define it with names and types, to make it more intuitive.

> TimeSlot and DateSlot, is working fine.

```
implicit object eitherDateOrTimeSlotFormat
  extends RootJsonFormat[Either[TimeSlot, DateSlot]] {

private val timeSlotTypeKey = "timeSlotType"
private val timeSlotValueKey = "timeSlotValue"

override def write(obj: Either[TimeSlot, DateSlot]): JsValue = obj match {
  case Left(timeSlot) ⇒
    JsObject(
      timeSlotTypeKey → JsString("timeSlot"),
      timeSlotValueKey → timeSlot.toJson
    )
  case Right(dateSlot) =>
    JsObject(
      timeSlotTypeKey → JsString("dateSlot"),
      timeSlotValueKey → dateSlot.toJson
    )
}

override def read(json: JsValue): Either[TimeSlot, DateSlot] = json match {
  case JsObject(fields)
      if fields.isDefinedAt("timeSlotType") && fields
        .isDefinedAt("timeSlotValue") ⇒
    fields("timeSlotType") match {
      case JsString(slotType) ⇒
        slotType match {
          case "timeSlot" ⇒
            Left(fields("timeSlotValue").convertTo[TimeSlot])
          case "dateSlot" ⇒
            Right(fields("timeSlotValue").convertTo[DateSlot])
          case _ ⇒
            throw DeserializationException(
              s"${json.compactPrint} did not match protocol"
            )
        }
      case _ ⇒
        throw DeserializationException(
          s"${json.compactPrint} did not match protocol"
        )
    }
}
```

}
It seems the tests is running forever, like if they were stuck in some kind of infinity-loop, and would of course be expected to just serialize, so my tests would assert the results.

Answer (score 0):

This was not a programmatically error, it seems there is a problem with either Idea Intellij community, Sbt test or scalac. But I manually tested the code instead of running inside the test-environment, and everything was fine.

[What i thought was Infinte-loop test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqhx6.png)